# What merits do we have making a private inner class final?

Tags: java, class, final

I went through some code today.  And I spotted something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    ...
    final private class SomeHandler implements Blahblah
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since no one should be able to access `SomeHandler` from outside, I fail to see why we should make it `final`.  Does anybody have some different insight?

Comment: Are you asking why it should be final, or why it should be private?

Comment: Best case: It is final because the author wanted to make it clear that no class should extend the `SomeHandler` class.

Comment: @CubeJockey I'm asking "why it should be final".

Comment: @DwB Yeah, that is the only thing I can see.

Comment: For those who downvoted and/or attempted to close this question, could you tell us your reasons?

Comment: It is final so no other inner class can extend it. Such a thing would be rare, so maybe there is an ugly static field lying around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a class as `final` has two related but distinct purposes.

1. It tells the compiler "do not allow this class to be extended".  This is done primarily to prevent mistakes.
2. It tells the reader "do not worry that this class might be extended".  This is to aid understanding.

In the case of a `private final` inner class, we can assume that one person writes or modifies the class and that they do it after understanding the design.  Thus, the likelihood of someone mistakenly extending a class that shouldn't be extended (by design) is small.

However, someone reading the code who needs to know is the `private` inner class might have been extended needs to scan the entire Java source file ... unless the class has been declared `final`.

Hence `final` could be serving a useful purpose ... in making the design manifest to improve readability.

---

On the other hand, the `final` in the example you found *could* have been added without any particular intent; i.e. it could simply be "redundant".

Comment: +1 I would only add that a *well-designed* Java class should almost always be made `final`, except when it is *intentionally* designed for extension through sub-classing. The fact that classes in the Java language are not final by default was a language design mistake, coming from the 80's/90's mentality that frequent (ab)use of class inheritance was a good idea. Modern works such as the "Effective Java", "Practical API Design", and "API Design for C++" books all recommended to make classes "final" by default and to avoid "virtual" methods in general.

Comment: Indeed, if an inner class is declared in a huge class, adding the `final` keyword will help a lot when searching things in the code.  I haven't thought about that before, good point!  :)

Comment: @Rogério Interesting.  But I remember there was once I wished I could override one of the methods in a class in some 3rd party library (open source), which was buggy.  I ended up copying the entire class and modified it in my own code.  Only _well-designed_ isn't enough, IMO.

Comment: @Rogério - I wouldn't say that.  It is opinion, even if that opinion is commonly held.